# My VBS script to close a powerpoint slide show no longer works

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a script which opens a powerpoint slide show with a single slide with a gif animation on it which says "Loading, please wait". The scipt then loads a large excel file in the background and after a delay it used to close the powerpoint slide show, leaving the Excel file visible. However, for some reason this no longer works.I get an error on this command:

> Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint Application")

The error mesage says: ActiveX component can't create object: 'GetObject'

I have made changes to neither the the VBS script nor the PPSX file since it last worked, but I have had to change my Microsoft Office suite from 2010 to 2007.

Both the PPSX and the Excel file (xlsm) open fine, it is just closing the powerpoint application which is a problem. Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Christopher

PS I have simply copied elements of othwe work found on this site and other to cretae the script, I am not able to write, or even really understand, scripts myself yet...

Answer (score 0):

Pure Voodoo based on problems like [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/540522-how-do-i-specify-powerpoint-application-version-visual-basic-applications.html):

Maybe the Office downgrade disabled/deleted/invalidated the version-independent ProgId "Powerpoint Application". Search the registry for a version-specific ProgId "Powerpoint Application.VERSION" and - if found - use that in your `GetObject()` call.